# Python - curve_fit applied to a table with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting

I want to optimize a function with 2 variables x,y over a set of data using curve_fit. So far, I have a program (see below) that works well with "complete" pandas dataframe. But I would like to use pandas dataframe with some undefined values (Nan) as entry data.

```
#Optimization of func over data_x_y
x = np.array(data_x_y.index)
y = np.array(data_x_y.columns)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)    
Z = data_x_y.values.T

xdata = np.vstack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel()))

fit_params, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, Z.ravel(), p0=p0, bounds=bounds)
```

I thought about putting random values instead of Nan values in the dataframe and using the parameter s of curve_fit to neglect these values, but this is clearly not the best way.

Therefore, is there an easy way to modify this program to use curve_fit, or do I need to define a cost function and use instead the minimize function of scipy.optimize ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you really want to use [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) to replace those `NaN`s

Comment: That could work with other data but in mine the Nan elements always appear for the smaller values of x : I guess it is better to interpolate when you know the inferior and superior value ?